# Wacom Tablet not detected ubuntu 20.04, HP probook x360 435 G7

Tags: 20.04, tablet, wacom

I'm using a HP Probook x360 435 G7 Laptop, with ubuntu 20.04 installed on it.
Neither the Wacom tablet is detected, nor the stylus.

This is with bluetooth already turned ON:
[image]

Here is the output of various commands:

```
abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$ dpkg -l | grep wacom
ii  libwacom-bin                                  1.3-2ubuntu3                                                amd64        Wacom model feature query library -- binaries
ii  libwacom-common                               1.3-2ubuntu3                                                all          Wacom model feature query library (common files)
ii  libwacom2:amd64                               1.3-2ubuntu3                                                amd64        Wacom model feature query library
ii  xserver-xorg-input-wacom                      1:0.39.0-0ubuntu1                                           amd64        X.Org X server -- Wacom input driver

abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$ xsetwacom  --list 
abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$ 


abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$ lspci  | grep -i wacom
abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$

abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 04f2:b6a6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP 5MP Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05c8:03dc Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00df Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$ sudo lsmod | grep -i wacom
wacom                 118784  0
usbhid                 57344  1 wacom
hid                   135168  7 i2c_hid,wacom,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,hid_generic,amd_sfh

abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN071B:00 04F3:312C Mouse               id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN071B:00 04F3:312C Touchpad            id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2513:00 04F3:2AD8                     id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2513:00 04F3:2AD8 Pen (0)             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN2513:00 04F3:2AD8 Eraser (0)          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP HD Camera: HP HD Camera                id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ELAN2513:00 04F3:2AD8                     id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=22   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP 5MP Camera: HP 5MP Camera              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Note that kde_wacom_tablet was installed and tried, and it crashed. It did not detect any tablet.

```
abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$ dmesg | grep -i tablet
[125263.396375] kde_wacom_table[330836]: segfault at 0 ip 0000560929fca05b sp 00007ffc3d2827e0 error 4 in kde_wacom_tabletfinder[560929fc6000+23000]
[125278.772338] kde_wacom_table[330942]: segfault at 0 ip 000055a94961a05b sp 00007ffc87c89700 error 4 in kde_wacom_tabletfinder[55a949616000+23000]
abhijit@abhijit-laptop:~$
```

Comment: Which model of Wacom Tablet?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your device uses an ELAN sensor. The libwacom tablet database doesn't include many ELAN sensors, and the GNOME Control Center won't let you configure any devices that aren't in the database. You can follow the [wacom-hid-descriptors "contributing" instructions](https://github.com/linuxwacom/wacom-hid-descriptors/#wacom-hid-descriptors) to share information about your system and hope someone can create a tablet definition from the data. They regularly create definitions for Wacom sensors but their developers aren't as familiar with ELAN hardware...